# How to delete and change JSON elements from JSON objects in a customized JSON file using nodejs?

Tags: json, node.js

Suppose I have a JSON file like this: {a: b, c: d};{e: f, g: h};{i: k, m: n}. the ';' is added by me to separate the JSON objects. Now I want to change the first element of the first JSON object from a: b to a: z. How can I do that without **rewriting the whole file**?

If someone has some other ways to record the information **other than using JSON file or database**,  can you please point it out?

thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful if you posted the raw JSON file. Do you want to change the object and update the file, or just change the object in memory?

Comment: Thanks, the raw JSON file is in the exactly same style as what I posted. I want to change the object and update the file.